# How to send info to stripe using cloud functions?

Tags: javascript, html, stripe-payments

i am trying to query my database and create variables that I can call later on the function when loading the checkout page. I am able to successfully deploy the function, but when it searches for the values, it fails. How can I write this function properly? I've been running in circles for weeks trying to figure this out. Thank you so much.

(This is how my database is set up)

```
studiopick
   studio
     users
        Gcsh31DCGAS2u2XXLuh8AbwBeap1
          email : "Test@gmail.com"
          firstName : "Test"
          lastName : "one"
          phoneNumber : "2223334567"
          prices
          |   roomA
          |     serviceOne
          |       numberInput : "300"
          |       serviceType : "mix n master"
           studioName : "Studio One"
           uid : "Gcsh31DCGAS2u2XXLuh8AbwBeap1"
```

(Cloud fucntion)

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.createStripeCheckout = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const querySnapshot = await admin
    .database()
    .ref("studiopick/studio/users/" + uid + "/prices/roomA/serviceOne/")
    .once("value");

    numberInput : numberInput
    serviceType : serviceType
    

  // Stripe init
  const stripe = require("stripe")(functions.config().stripe.secret_key);
  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    payment_method_types: ["card"],
    mode: "payment",
    success_url: "http://localhost:5500/success",
    cancel_url: "http://localhost:5500/cancel",
    shipping_address_collection: {
      allowed_countries: ["US"],
    },
    line_items: [
      {
        quantity: 1,
        price_data: {
          currency: "usd",
          unit_amount: numberInput * 100, // 10000 = 100 USD
          product_data: {
            name: serviceType,
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  });

  return {
    id: session.id,
  };
});
```

Comment: What is this: `numberInput : numberInput`? And `serviceType : serviceType`?  Are those meant to be there?  Also, should `success_url` and `cancel_url` begin with `localhost:5500` in a deployed function?

Comment: Those are the specific variables that are being called from the database that I want to send to stripe